# Puppeteer cluster launches blank chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I am facing an issue with Puppeteer-cluster launching additional chrome black blank pages, even though the puppeteer itself is headless: true. I wonder if I can prevent this behaviour? Or maybe the blank pages won't be shown when the app will be deployed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8O0r.png)

Here is my cluster initialisation:

```
    const initCluster = async () => {
        process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);
        return await Cluster.launch({
            concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
            maxConcurrency: 4,
            timeout: 10000,
            puppeteerOptions: {
                headless: true,
                args: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-notifications',
                    '--disable-extensions',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
                ]
            }
        });
    };
```

I tried using various puppeteer options and cluster options, so I hoped one of them will stop the blank pages from showing, but nothing helped, and there is no info on the internet.

Comment: I've been seeing this too on Windows on normal Puppeteer as of a few days ago, so I don't think it's specific to puppeteer-cluster. Can you provide your package.json and OS version? How are you deploying your app (what target environment)? Thanks for the info. I'm using Puppeteer 19.7.2, Windows 10.0.19045 Build 19045, 64 bit, PowerShell 5.1.19041.2673. You may want to open an issue on Puppeteer's github if there isn't one already.